# text-overflow: ellipsis in table-cell without width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a responsive table width `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in the middle cell that looks like this:

`| Button 1 | A one-lined text that is too long and has to be... | Button 2 |`

The whole table should have `width: 100%;` to be as large as the device. I can't set a fixed width on `Button 1` nor `Button 2` since the application is multilingual (a `max-width` should be possible though).

I can try whatever I want, the `...` only appears when I set a fixed width. How can I tell the middle cell to "use the space available" without the help of JavaScript?

Comment: It would help if you post what you already tried? At least some base we can copy paste and modify ;)

Comment: I only tried a table with one row and three cells...

Comment: :) I meant also the css you tried out, because there's I think the hard part

Comment: As this answer (and others, on similar questions) suggests:http://stackoverflow.com/a/28492910/1339923 ...setting `max-width` is the key.

Answer (score 81):

This is not really a clean solution, but it uses no JS and works in every browser I've tested.

My solution consists in wrapping the cell's contents inside a table with `table-layout: fixed` and `width: 100%`.

See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V83Ae/38/).

Here's the full solution:

```
<table class="main-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="nowrap">Button 1</td>
        <td>
            <table class="fixed-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus doloremque magni illo reprehenderit consequuntur quia dicta labore veniam distinctio quod iure vitae porro nesciunt. Minus ipsam facilis! Velit sapiente numquam.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="nowrap">Button 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.main-table {
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-table {
    /* magic */
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    
    /*not really necessary, removes extra white space */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.fixed-table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.nowrap {
    /* used to keep buttons' text in a single line,
     * remove this class to allow natural line-breaking.
     */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

It's not really clear what's the intent for the side buttons, hence I've used `white-space: nowrap` to keep them in the same line. Depending on the use case, you may prefer to apply a `min-width` and let them line-break naturally.

Comment: Perfecto, it worked like charm.... I was awarding you bounty points but SO says it can't be done before 23 more hrs...

Comment: Heheh no worries, I'd like to see a cleaner answer than this too so let's wait and see. I actually have this answer's code in a production environment, it doesn't feel really clean but yeah, I struggled with it for days and this was the only solution that actually worked in every browser.

Comment: @AtulGupta thanks for trying to add my fiddle to the OP (saw it on the edit review queue), but I guess it's not really the place for it. `;)` Thanks for upvoting my answer, but let's wait to see if anyone comes up with a cleaner solution in the next 24 hours and then you can award the bounty when you feel like. `:P`

Comment: +1 for the solution, because it does not effect current styling of your table. just 1 cell to update.

Comment: awesome (common meaning)

Comment: for anyone who, like me, liked the answer but doesn't want all that extra markup here's [css tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40518661/2518317)

Comment: This looks gross, but it does work very solidly, even in IE. I don't want to use css tables, I prefer to use actual tables. This solution is easily encapsulated in an angular component or the like.

Answer (score 19):

Set your 100% width on the table and specify a `fixed` table-layout:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Then, set the following for whichever table cell should have the ellipsis:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Voila! Responsive table with an ellipsis overflow!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VyxES/

Comment: It is a nice solution, the only drawback of applying `table-layout: fixed` is that it splits the width of cells equally (unless manually set) instead of based on content.

Comment: True, but the OP requested a solution that did not specify a width on individual table cells (and thanks!).

Comment: Agreed, big drawback, the OP wanted the 1st and 3rd cells to be only as wide as their content and have the center cell take up the remaining width.

Comment: @JonathanJulian: Please point out where in the OP that requirement is stated.

Comment: Thank you for this - of all the answers I've read on this subject, this is the one that worked for me.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté & JonathanJulian I have a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40518661/2518317) without `fixed` layout below

Comment: This worked for us. We hate the nested table markup, and the fact that this is even necessary, but it is the most robust and cross-browser solution that doesn't involve static table cell widths or abandoning semantic table markup for the entire app just to get div-based tables in the 2% of the cases where we need to truncate some text.

Answer (score 10):

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="ellipsis"> A very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
td {
    position: relative;
}

.ellipsis {
    /*Here is the trick:*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /*End of the trick*/

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me. I saw that, span is get top: 10 by default. It will be beneficial to add a top value in elipsis class.

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner way would be to simply set a max-width on the td.

Based on @Fabrício Matté's reply,

http://jsfiddle.net/V83Ae/89/

```
<table class="main-table">
<tr>
    <td class="nowrap">Button 1</td>
    <td class="truncate">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus doloremque magni illo reprehenderit consequuntur quia dicta labore veniam distinctio quod iure vitae porro nesciunt. Minus ipsam facilis! Velit sapiente numquam.</td>
    <td class="nowrap">Button 2</td>
</tr>
```

And

```
body { margin: 0; }

.main-table {
    width: 100%;
}

.truncate {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space  : nowrap;
    overflow     : hidden;
    max-width    : 100px; /* Can be any size, just small enough */
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I have no idea why this works, but it does, so if someone can figure how why applying a max-width works then please let me know as I did it by accident.

Comment: This is wonderful and works exactly as expected. Really saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head for hours, with no solution that worked, finally found it.

The element you want for the base of the overflow nees a min/max width, where the max is inferior to the min width. You can then overflow the lement or a child of it, where you can set the with whatever way you choose: %, px, auto.

I tried it in more than one tricky situation and it works on all.

I'll try to post a fiidle with my examples but this should help you going.

```css
/* Apply on base element for proper overflow */
max-width: 1px;
min-width: 10000px;

/* Apply on self or child, according to need */
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer since it's the most clean working solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/btx522ak/1/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Button 1
  </div>
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="lockText">
      A one-lined text that is too long and has to be...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Button 2
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to set up a table layout with a cell that takes up leftover space first (css tables, mind you!).

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position : relative;
  width : auto;

  /*make it easier to see what's going on*/
  padding : 2px;
  border : 1px solid gray;
}

.container > .fill {
  width : 100%;
}
```

Then add your text that constrains itself within.

```css
.lockText {
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[update]
My apologies, does not seem to work 'just like that': http://jsfiddle.net/kQKfc/1/

Will leave it here though, because it certain situations it does the trick for us.
[/update]

We have this css in our project, give it a shot:

```
.nowr
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```