# How to add ellipsis to table cells with dynamic width with only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've been searching SO for a while and haven't found a similar solution. I'm trying create a table in a web page that would have the following characteristics:

1. Table width = 100% always (no scroll is needed to see all columns; table takes all the available width)
2. Table cells are compacted (e.g.: no extra space is used unless necessary)
3. If cells are too wide, crop and use ellipsis.
4. All cells are 1 line height
5. I don't know how many columns will be shown (could be ~40) - which I believe rules out `max-width` for the cells?

One solution I saw [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826992/text-overflow-ellipsis-in-table-cell-without-width) uses inner `<table />`s but playing with the suggested fiddle you can tell fields aren't compacted ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/V83Ae/7/)).

**EDIT:** I'm using Knockout so my table structure goes as follows (Note I don't know how many columns are showing):

`<table class="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                    <th data-bind="text: name" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
                <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
                    <td data-bind="text: $data" />
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table`

The current CSS (that doesn't work so anything is welcome):

`.grid tr td {
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
     -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`

**EDIT 2:**  [Adding a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcBeX/)

Ideas? Links? Dups?

Comment: Please post your existing table structure and css.

Comment: "Dups?"  That is your job to look for existing similar answers, not our job to mark yours as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware. Just couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Try wrapping the cell contents in a div, and put the styles on it instead of the td.

Comment: So, what about ellipses again?

Comment: Thanks @dg988, tried - but I get the same result: Either the cell ignores the ellipsis or when I add `max-width`, the table ends up wider than `100%`.

Comment: How about `table-layout: fixed;` on your table.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` will violate requirement #2 - the cells won't be compacted if they don't _have_ to take all the space

Comment: Here a fiddle to try: http://jsfiddle.net/LcBeX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the table `width` with `table-layout:fixed;`
In this way it is forced to have the specified `width` or `max-width`.

If I understood correctly your requirement
http://jsfiddle.net/3vLdq8pe/5/
 (note the frame div is just to show the limit in smaller size)

Comment: The title says "with dynamic width." This explicitly disables dynamic width and forces all columns to equal width by default. Then you have to manually pixel-nudge by putting an explicit width on every column in your entire app.