# Ellipsis in 100% width table

Tags: html, css

My basic ellipsis style and mark-up is as follows ([fiddle](http://jsbin.com/kasabaci/1/edit?html,css,output)):

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Row Start (1)</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">Lectus ligula uspendisse tiam per sodales feugiat tempus ante pede vitae amet conubia raesent tincidunt n feugiat id ad mi dapibus</td>
    <td>Row End</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row Start (2)</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">Placerat consectetuer inceptos dictum mollis adipiscing placerat sed tincidunt ullam id onec lectus sagittis consequat conubia tempus eleifend ad orbi risus hac dolor accumsan commodo a eros ed consectetuer odio feugiat dignissim dictum at ullam ligula mollis sollicitudin rutrum viverra in feugiat conubia metus uspendisse sit non imperdiet unc liquam</td>
    <td>Row End</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

... but it just makes my table stretch to fit everything in a single line and document gets a nice horizontal scroll. Same code works as expected for non-table block-level elements.

Is there a workaround that doesn't force me to use fixed widths?

Comment: How about adding `table-layout:fixed` and `width: 100%` to `table`?

Comment: Can you share the working code for block-level elements?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai - Just the CSS you see plus `<div class="ellipsis">Long text</div>`

Comment: See if this helps. [text-overflow: ellipsis in table-cell without width](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14826992/1331430)

Comment: Sorry, I've just found [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826992/text-overflow-ellipsis-in-table-cell-without-width) with an excellent answer. I don't know why I couldn't' find it before.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/jehaxequ/1/edit

TD **max width** is a solution here. If you don't know the max width of td, the problem isn't easy to do with CSS, however a little jquery or javascript can be used to calculate the max width of td, and add it "live" to your element properties.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but every time I've fiddled with JavaScript to do this kind of stuff I've ended up regretting it. It's impossible to get it right if you want to account for dynamic scripts or just window resizing.

Comment: ... whatever... your fiddle does work and it's apparently ignoring the  `max-width: 300px;` style :-?

Comment: It works, but width of td is always recalculated to percentage of a table :).

Comment: Not in my actual mark-up :) But I need to have a look at it carefully.

Comment: OK, no problem. This will help You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765817/why-does-css-td-width-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Add a `max-width` property.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/kasabaci/2/edit)